# Paypal smart buttons: subscriptions without shipping address, no billing info

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am using PayPal Smart Buttons and want to create subscriptions, but I don't need to require billing address or contact information (phone, email) from users.
For one-time checkout, it is possible to add `'NO_SHIPPING'`.

```
                application_context: {
                    "shipping_preference": 'NO_SHIPPING',
                }
```

but for subscriptions it's not working

here is my code

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY_CLIENT_ID&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
```

```
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'pill',
            color: 'blue',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'subscribe'
        },
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                /* Creates the subscription */
                plan_id: '<my-plan-id>',
                application_context: {
                    shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING',
                }
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            alert(data.subscriptionID); // You can add optional success message for the subscriber here
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Renders the PayPal button
```

is there any way to disable **Shipping address** and **contact info**

I know other sites and I've checked, they don't require a shipping address. Any ideas?

I checked their docs but no luck

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sandbox-Environment/Subscription-with-no-shipping-address/m-p/1541975#M2382

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/Subscription-with-no-shipping-address/td-p/1541905

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what's different about your example,

```
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
            "plan_id": "P-.......",
            "application_context": {
                "shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING"
            }
        });
      },
```

Works fine for me. There is no shipping address selection in the checkout.